# Using regex on MVC routes for controller action to allow only calls that don't contain a given word

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following actions defined for two seperate controllers -

Controller A -

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/{configurationId:int}/device/")]
public ActionResult AddDevice()
```

Controller B -

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("~/{configurationId:int}/{fieldname:string}/")]
public ActionResult EditConfiguration()
```

I need to leave the routes defined as is due to design considerations, etc. I am trying to add a regular expression to Controller B action to exclude the word 'device' for fieldname so that the routes don't 'collide'. This is what I have and it seems to work in regex testing tool.

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("~/{configurationId:int}/{fieldName:regex(^\b([a-z0-9-]+)\b(?<!device)$)}/")]
public ActionResult EditConfiguration()
```

If I call it with this route it says it cannot find the resource. Any ideas/suggestions on how to alter my regex so this will work? -

```
configuration/3/lock-timeout/
```

Comment: Is it intentional that you are using `~` because it will override the route prefix so the `configuration/` is what might be causing the problem.

Comment: Yes that is intentional. The route prefix actually isn't defined and the full url just isn't listed in my post. Whenever the request is sent from both places in the application they contain the correct prefixes. The configuration/3/lock-timeout is just the last part of the route. The other request has the same prefix but with configuration/3/device/ as the last part. So, as you can see the routes end up being ambiguous and I get an error when I try to send a request to either route. That is why I tried to address it using the regex.

Comment: Just to elaborate the error I get when I remove the regex from my Controller B route ([Route("~/{configurationId:int}/{fieldname}/")]) is -'Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out. Turns out my regex was too complicated. Here is the working expression for anyone looking to put a route constraint to exclude a given word (in my case 'device':

```
[Route("~/{configurationId:int}/{fieldName:regex(^(?!.*device).*$)}/")]
```